# Using a comma-separated string in shell to update a JSON list with jq?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

How to append value to json key using?

```
val=""text"",""text"",""text""

jq '.doc[1].DEF[3].value="update comma separated val here" <<< "$jsonStr"
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: Your assignment is **exactly** the same as `val=text,text,text`; the quotes do nothing whatsoever (they don't become part of the shell variable's value, because they're parsed as syntax). You can verify this with `echo "$val"`.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to split a string on commas to generate a list, and use your list in jq, that might look like:

```
val=text1,text2,text3
jq --arg val "$val" '.whatever.item |= ($val | split(","))' <<<'{"whatever": {}}'
```

Note:

- There's no point to paired double-quote sets in the shell assignment -- they literally cancel each other out and don't become part of the variable's value.
- The `jq` argument `--arg` is used to pass that variable from a shell context to a jq context.
- The `|=` construct is used to modify a nested value while still evaluating to the larger document.